# "Code for a living" section on SO.blog seems broken

Tags: bug, blog

Today , I visited [Code for a living](http://www.stackoverflow.blog/code-for-a-living) section of SO blog and it shows as too much zoomed and with broken formatting as shown in image below although other sections are working great.

[image]

as you can see , i had to reduced the zoomed level from 110% to 50% to see the content but still the formatting looks broken and even the content formatting under these links also seems broken.

Chrome Version 55.0.2883.87 m  ( in case required )

Comment: Probably they forgot to include CSS on page.

Comment: @Tushar yeah seems like a HTML view only

Comment: favicon is wrong too (bad quality image).

Comment: It looks fixed at this point.

Comment: @JoeKennedy yup it's done now , you can post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bug has been fixed on Dec 23 maybe around 22:15 as First reported by @joe Kennedy